# Double to string conversion (engineering format)

Tags: c#, double, string-formatting

I'm looking for a method to use very specific string format:

```
 -2.71405E-03  0.00000E+00 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03  0.00000E+00 -2.71405E-03
 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03
 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03 -5.42809E-03 -2.71405E-03 -2.71405E-03
```

It is format used in UFF58 file. This format is described with FORTRAN format string `E13.5`, which means 13 (unlike in languages like C/C++, it's also upper bound) characters, 5 decimal digits.
I've this code:

```
double d = -2.71405E-03;
d.ToString( "E5" ).Dump();
```

In LINQPad this gives output: `-2.71405E-003`.

I can't find any property of `NumberFormatInfo` class, that can limit size (character count used) of exponent. Any idea how to solve it with the change of format string or NumberFormatInfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to have 5 digits after the decimal point regardless, you can do this:

```
double d = -2.71405E-03;
d.ToString("0.00000E+00");
```

Comment: You should use `E+00`, not `E-00`, because `-` does not produce the `+` sign in the exponent.

Comment: Thanks for that, you're right it would give `Enn` instead of `E+nn`! Changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string MyString = d.ToString("0.#####E-00");
```

Comment: +1 (deleted a space in the format string) I'll add that, considering the format is fixed, he should specify the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: The `#`s mean that the format is not really fixed width. For example, for 0, it produces `0E00`, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: exactly, one of values in my example data is `0.00000E+00`, which means, that using `#` is not a correct solution here

thanks anyway, because after seeing this answer only, I could create proper solution myself